# Naming of the class of Artin-Tits groups corresponding to finite simply laced diagrams with relations up to order $3$

Tags: group-theory

Artin-Tits groups come in different classes with an agreed upon naming, such as right-angled Artin-Tits groups, Artin-Tits groups of spherical type, of large type etc.

However, I could not find a name in the literature for the class of Artin-Tits groups arising from finite simply-laced diagrams with relations only up to degree three.

To be more specific: Given a simply-laced graph (i.e. a graph with at most one edge between two vertices) where edges may be labeled by numbers in $\{3,4,\dots\}$, its associated Artin-Tits group is given by generators being the vertices, with relations $st\dots=ts\dots$, where both sides have length the number on the edge between vertex $s$ and vertex $t$, and the relation $st=ts$ if there is no edge.

I am wondering if there is a name for Artin-Tits groups coming from those graphs where every edge is labeled with a three, i.e. we only have relations $st=ts$ and $sts=tst$.

This class of Artin-Tits groups would include e.g. the Artin-Braid group, and more generally the spherical type Artin-Tits groups of type $A_n$,$D_n$ etc. but excluding those having higher order relations. But of course this class would also posses non-spherical type Artin-Tits groups.

If there is no agreed upon name for this class of Artin-Tits groups, is it because they simply do not share enough properties that would make this class interesting and handy to consider?